# How to automount home directory from remote machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, sshfs

I have two computers connected in network and I would like them to share my home directory. I thought of mounting on one of them home directory from another computer.

I may happen that one of those computers is off, so it should remount home directory when it is possible (or on access).

I prefer encrypted solution (sshfs?)

I will need this directory to run some parallel programs that should access files in home directory, so it should be reliable - is sshfs good for this? Or should I look for something else?

I'm using Ubuntu, but other Linux solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use NFS, SMBFS, SSHFS or whatever you want with Autofs.

It's do what you're searching. It mounts on demand a share and could umount on idle (if you configure it).

In all the case, if one of the servers reboot, the client side try to auto-mount the share as a request is made.

Comment: I was looking at autofs earlier, but to mount sshfs passwordless I needed to create passwordless login from root to account on remote computer. It isn't nice solution :). And what about sshfs? I've heard that it causes some problems sometimes.

Comment: No, you can specify the user you wish with sshfs and autofs. Here is a documentation : http://www.deimos.fr/blocnotesinfo/index.php?title=AutoFS_:_montage_et_d%C3%A9montage_de_partages

Comment: Hm, no :). Problem is that on my local machine I have to generate ssh key for root user and add it on remote machine in authorized_keys. autofs mounts as a root user and I would like it to mount as some other user, because for that user I have login with ssh key.